# Removing a column causes trouble

Tags: tables

I have removed a column in this table, but when I remove the last value in the column the whole table gets messed up. Does anyone know why and what I should do?

Second, I want to have a title and some text prior to the table. However, with my limited knowledge, I can´t figure out how I can do that.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        
        \centering
        \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}llcccc@{}}
            \toprule \toprule
            \Block{}<\bfseries>{Admission \\requirements \\ for Economics \\(MSc)}  &
            \Block{}<\bfseries>{Courses \\ completed}                               &
            \Block{}<\bfseries>{Date of \\ completion}                              &
            \textbf{ECTS}                                        & 
            \Block{}<\bfseries>{Degree  program \\ (B.A. Economics) }                                      
            \\ \midrule
            
            \Block{4-1}{Microeconomics \\ (30 ECTS)}& Microeconomics 1 & 22.11.2019  & 10 &  UiO \\
            & Welfare Economics     & 15.02.2013    &7&  12 &  SDU \\
            & Strategy and Markets  & 01.07.2015  & 15 &  SDU \\ 
            & Behavioral Economics  & 01.07.2015   & 15 &  SDU \\ \midrule
            
            \Block{2-1}{Macroeconomics \\(30 ECTS)} & Macroeconomics 1  & 22.04.2014   & 7.5&  UiO \\
            & Macroeconomics 2      & 15.02.2013    & 12 &  SDU \\ \midrule
            
            \Block{}{Mathematics \\(30 ECTS)}       & Mathematics I         & 22.04.2014    & 7.5&  UiO \\ \midrule
            
            \Block{4-1}{Interdiciplinary \\ (30 ECTS)}& International Economics      & 22.11.2019  & 10 &  SDU \\
            & Economics of European Integration     & 15.02.2013   & 12 &  SDU \\
            & Applied Economics  & 01.07.2015   & 15 &  SDU \\ \midrule
            
            \Block{2-1}{Statistics \\ (30 ECTS)}    & Statistics 1          & 22.04.2014   & 7.5&  UiO \\
            & Regression Analysis   & 15.02.2013   & 12 &  SDU \\ 
            \midrule \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{\label{tab:table-name} The following table...}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to remove an entry in the row “Welfare Economics” and also to remove the corresponding column specification.

Remember that `NiceTabular` usually needs more than one LaTeX run to stabilize.

Here's a less confusing input, where I also implemented the golden rule of *never using double rules*.

Text above the table can be input normally, as shown in the code below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}

Here I add some text before the table, long enough to split across lines;
it should be enough to add some more words, hopefully.

\bigskip

\centering

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}llccc@{}}
\toprule
\Block{}<\bfseries>{Admission \\requirements \\ for Economics \\(MSc)} &
\Block{}<\bfseries>{Courses \\ completed} &
\Block{}<\bfseries>{Date of \\ completion} &
\textbf{ECTS} &
\Block{}<\bfseries>{Degree  program \\ (B.A. Economics)} \\
\midrule

\Block{4-1}{Microeconomics \\ (30 ECTS)}
& Microeconomics 1                  & 22.11.2019 & 10   &  UiO \\
& Welfare Economics                 & 15.02.2013 & 12   &  SDU \\
& Strategy and Markets              & 01.07.2015 & 15   &  SDU \\ 
& Behavioral Economics              & 01.07.2015 & 15   &  SDU \\

\midrule

\Block{2-1}{Macroeconomics \\(30 ECTS)}
& Macroeconomics 1                  & 22.04.2014 &  7.5 &  UiO \\
& Macroeconomics 2                  & 15.02.2013 & 12   &  SDU \\

\midrule

\Block{}{Mathematics \\(30 ECTS)}
& Mathematics I                     & 22.04.2014 &  7.5 &  UiO \\

\midrule

\Block{3-1}{Interdisciplinary \\ (30 ECTS)}
& International Economics           & 22.11.2019 & 10   &  SDU \\
& Economics of European Integration & 15.02.2013 & 12   &  SDU \\
& Applied Economics                 & 01.07.2015 & 15   &  SDU \\

\midrule

\Block{2-1}{Statistics \\ (30 ECTS)}
& Statistics 1                      & 22.04.2014 &  7.5 &  UiO \\
& Regression Analysis               & 15.02.2013 & 12   &  SDU \\ 

\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\caption{\label{tab:table-name}The table shows something}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Have a nice day:)